# WSO2 AuthenticationAdmin Logout

Tags: authentication, soap, logout, wso2

I am working with version 4.1.0 of the WSO2 Identity Server. I have used the WSO2 AuthenticationAdmin services (localhost:9443/services/AuthenticationAdmin) to login, check authenticator, etc. There is also an operation for 'logout'.

When soapUI generates the logout request, it does not contain any noteworthy elements, as is confirmed by the schema (xsd) with the namespace http://authentication.services.core.carbon.wso2.org. The SOAP request body is as follows.

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:aut="http://authentication.services.core.carbon.wso2.org">
 <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
     <aut:logout/>
 </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

When sending a request, the RAW response is as follows.

```
HTTP/1.1 202 Accepted
Date: Wed, 26 Jun 2013 08:29:48 GMT
Server: WSO2 Carbon Server
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=94784CC9FC03E9FA3822CFDDAD0D36F6; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

First of all, do I think there is no SOAP message in the response. Also, the HTTP status is 202, which means that the request is accepted for processing, but the processing has not yet been completed.

How do I logout with this service?

What elements should be added to the < aut:logout > ?

Should a JSESSIONID be added to the header of the request?

How can this logout be combined with the loginWithRememberMeOption ?

------- UPDATE
After reviewing the xsd I saw that a wsa:action must be added to the SOAP Header. After doing this, I received the following reply. This reply asks for a MessageID. But I am not sure what this value should be.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
   <soapenv:Header xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
      <wsa:Action>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/fault</wsa:Action>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <soapenv:Fault>
         <soapenv:Code>
            <soapenv:Value>soapenv:Sender</soapenv:Value>
            <soapenv:Subcode>
               <soapenv:Value xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">wsa:MessageAddressingHeaderRequired</soapenv:Value>
            </soapenv:Subcode>
         </soapenv:Code>
         <soapenv:Reason>
            <soapenv:Text xml:lang="en-US">A required header representing a Message Addressing Property is not present</soapenv:Text>
         </soapenv:Reason>
         <soapenv:Detail>
            <wsa:ProblemHeaderQName xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">wsa:MessageID</wsa:ProblemHeaderQName>
         </soapenv:Detail>
      </soapenv:Fault>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

When adding a generated MessageID, the is once again an empty SOAP reply with a HTTP 202 status.

Comment: Afaik when you login, an HTTP session is created and the session id cookie is sent to you. When you perform a logout you should set this cookie as a header request.

Comment: Hi Adrian. I have tried this, as follows:
- Left the generated soap request for logout as it was.
- Added a header in the SOAP request called 'cookie' with value 'JSESSIONID=EC91C18055FD38EF0FB112D301386B25; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly' (Just as i received it on login)
- Enabled WS Adressing
- Enabled generated MessageID

The response is an empty SOAP response, again with HTTP status 202.
When I do not enable WS Addressing, the response is also empty, 202.
When I enable WS Adressing, but not add a MessageID, the SOAP fault says that I have to add it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logout method just invalidates the session.

You just call the logout operation as it is from the soapUI. There are no parameters to it.

If you look at the AuthenticationAdmin WSDL, you can see that there is no output for logout operation. That's why you get HTTP 202 status code.

You can view the WSDL by changing `<HideAdminServiceWSDLs>` configuration to false in carbon.xml (/repository/conf/carbon.xml)

`<HideAdminServiceWSDLs>false</HideAdminServiceWSDLs>`

Type following in your browser to view the WSDL.

https://:9443/services/AuthenticationAdmin?wsdl

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Isuru, it helps a bit. Can you confirm that the Identity Server will not provide a definitive response whether the user has indeed successfully logged out?

Comment: The logout operation just invalidates the session. Ideally, you will be logged out automatically when the session is invalidated in the server. You can see it from the source: https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/kernel/branches/4.1.0/core/org.wso2.carbon.core.services/4.1.0/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/core/services/authentication/AuthenticationAdmin.java