# WSO2: How to logout a user that has obtained a 'rememberMeCookie'

Tags: authentication, soap, wso2, logout, wso2-identity-server

I am using WSO2 Identity Server 4.1.0 to perform basic authentication. It is possible to call the AuthenticationAdmin webservice, which contains a 'loginWithRememberMeOption'. The user will then obtain a 'rememberMeCookie', with which he can log in, even if his session (JSESSION) has expired.

I have learned that the loginWithRememberMeOption also has a timeout: 7 days, and that this time cannot be modified: [WSO2 Authentication, adding/modifing timeout to the RememberMe cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17340124/wso2-authentication-adding-modifing-timeout-to-the-rememberme-cookie)

The AuthenticationAdmin service also provides a 'logout' operation. Unfortunately, this operation will only invalidate the session. So if a user has a rememeberMeCookie, he will still be able to login: [WSO2 AuthenticationAdmin Logout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17315513/wso2-authenticationadmin-logout)

The question is, how do I logout a user that has obtained a rememeberMeCookie? Preferably using the AuthenticationAdmin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand there is no direct way to logout a user with a remember me cookie.

I went through the code. Once you login with remember me option, a `UUID` is generated. Refer `org.wso2.carbon.core.services.authentication.AuthenticationAdmin.loginWithRememberMeOption(String, String, String)` method in [AuthenticationAdmin](https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/kernel/branches/4.1.0/core/org.wso2.carbon.core.services/4.1.0/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/core/services/authentication/AuthenticationAdmin.java)

The cookie is then saved in database. When you login with remember me cookie, the cookie is checked from the user store. Refer `org.wso2.carbon.user.api.UserStoreManager.isValidRememberMeToken(String, String)`. You can check the [JDBC implementation](https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/kernel/branches/4.1.0/core/org.wso2.carbon.user.core/4.1.0/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/user/core/jdbc/JDBCUserStoreManager.java).

So, in order to logout, you might have to clear the cookie from the user store.

Please report a [JIRA](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/CARBON) issue, if you think it might be useful to add a method to clear the cookie.